# Checking for a not null, not blank String in Java

Tags: java, string

I am trying to check if a Java String is not `null`, not empty and not whitespace.

In my mind, this code should have been quite up for the job.

```
public static boolean isEmpty(String s) {
    if ((s != null) && (s.trim().length() > 0))
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

As per documentation, [`String.trim()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) should work thus:

> Returns a copy of the string, with leading and trailing whitespace omitted.
>
> If this `String` object represents an empty character sequence, or the first and last characters of character sequence represented by this `String` object both have codes greater than `'\u0020'` (the space character), then a reference to this `String` object is returned.

However, `apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.java` does it a little differently.

```
public static boolean isBlank(String str) {
    int strLen;
    if (str == null || (strLen = str.length()) == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < strLen; i++) {
        if ((Character.isWhitespace(str.charAt(i)) == false)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

As per documentation, [`Character.isWhitespace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace%28char%29):

> Determines if the specified character is white space according to Java. A character is a Java whitespace character if and only if it satisfies one of the following criteria:
>
> - It is a Unicode space character (`SPACE_SEPARATOR`, `LINE_SEPARATOR`, or `PARAGRAPH_SEPARATOR`) but is not also a non-breaking space (`'\u00A0'`, `'\u2007'`, `'\u202F'`).
> - It is `'\t'`, U+0009 HORIZONTAL TABULATION.
> - It is `'\n'`, U+000A LINE FEED.
> - It is `'\u000B'`, U+000B VERTICAL TABULATION.
> - It is `'\f'`, U+000C FORM FEED.
> - It is `'\r'`, U+000D CARRIAGE RETURN.
> - It is `'\u001C'`, U+001C FILE SEPARATOR.
> - It is `'\u001D'`, U+001D GROUP SEPARATOR.
> - It is `'\u001E'`, U+001E RECORD SEPARATOR.
> - It is `'\u001F'`, U+001F UNIT SEPARATOR.

If I am not mistaken - or might be I am just not reading it correctly - the `String.trim()`  should take away any of the characters that are being checked by `Character.isWhiteSpace()`. All of them see to be above `'\u0020'`.

In this case, the simpler `isEmpty` function seems to be covering all the scenarios that the lengthier `isBlank` is covering.

1. Is there a string that will make the `isEmpty` and `isBlank` behave differently in a test case?
2. Assuming there are none, is there any other consideration because of which I should choose `isBlank` and not use `isEmpty`?

For those interested in actually running a test, here are the methods and unit tests.

```
public class StringUtil {

    public static boolean isEmpty(String s) {
        if ((s != null) && (s.trim().length() > 0))
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    public static boolean isBlank(String str) {
        int strLen;
        if (str == null || (strLen = str.length()) == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < strLen; i++) {
            if ((Character.isWhitespace(str.charAt(i)) == false)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

And unit tests

```
@Test
public void test() {
    
    String s = null; 
    assertTrue(StringUtil.isEmpty(s)) ;
    assertTrue(StringUtil.isBlank(s)) ;
    
    s = ""; 
    assertTrue(StringUtil.isEmpty(s)) ;
    assertTrue(StringUtil.isBlank(s)); 
    
    s = " "; 
    assertTrue(StringUtil.isEmpty(s)) ;
    assertTrue(StringUtil.isBlank(s)) ;
    
    s = "   "; 
    assertTrue(StringUtil.isEmpty(s)) ;
    assertTrue(StringUtil.isBlank(s)) ;
    
    s = "   a     "; 
    assertTrue(StringUtil.isEmpty(s)==false) ;    
    assertTrue(StringUtil.isBlank(s)==false) ;       
    
}
```

Update: It was a really interesting discussion - and this is why I love Stack Overflow and the folks here. By the way, coming back to the question, we got:

- A program showing which all characters will make the behave differently. The code is at https://ideone.com/ELY5Wv. Thanks @Dukeling.
- A performance related reason for choosing the standard `isBlank()`. Thanks @devconsole.
- A comprehensive explanation by @nhahtdh. Thanks mate.

Comment: +1 for formatting and clarity.

Comment: Note that with both functions, `null` is accepted and will return `true`.

Comment: @Anirudh no, the `&&` is correct

Comment: @Thrakbad ohh..yes you are right

Comment: I am wondering why you don't write isEmpty simply as `public static boolean isEmpty(String s) { return (s == null) || s.trim().isEmpty(); }` . I am always somewhat confused if someone uses a whole if statement to express just a negation.

Answer (score 32):

> Is there a string that will make the `isEmpty` and `isBlank` behave differently in a test case?

Note that [`Character.isWhitespace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace%28int%29) can recognize Unicode characters and return `true` for Unicode whitespace characters.

> Determines if the specified character is white space according to Java. A character is a Java whitespace character if and only if it satisfies one of the following criteria:
>
> - It is a Unicode space character (`SPACE_SEPARATOR`, `LINE_SEPARATOR`, or `PARAGRAPH_SEPARATOR`) but is not also a non-breaking space (`'\u00A0'`, `'\u2007'`, `'\u202F'`).
> - `[...]`

On the other hand, `trim()` method would trim all control characters whose code points are below U+0020 and the space character (U+0020).

Therefore, the two methods would behave differently at presence of a Unicode whitespace character. For example: `"\u2008"`. **Or** when the string contains control characters that are not consider whitespace by `Character.isWhitespace` method. For example: `"\002"`.

If you were to write a regular expression to do this (which is slower than doing a loop through the string and check):

- `isEmpty()` would be equivalent to `.matches("[\\x00-\\x20]*")`
- `isBlank()` would be equivalent to `.matches("\\p{javaWhitespace}*")`

(The `isEmpty()` and `isBlank()` method both allow for `null` String reference, so it is not exactly equivalent to the regex solution, but putting that aside, it is equivalent).

Note that `\p{javaWhitespace}`, as its name implied, is Java-specific syntax to access the character class defined by `Character.isWhitespace` method.

> Assuming there are none, is there any other consideration because of which I should choose `isBlank` and not use `isEmpty`?

It depends. However, I think the explanation in the part above should be sufficient for you to decide. To sum up the difference:

- `isEmpty()` will consider the string is empty if it contains only control characters<sup>1</sup> below U+0020 and space character (U+0020)
- `isBlank` will consider the string is empty if it contains only whitespace characters as defined by `Character.isWhitespace` method, which includes Unicode whitespace characters.

<sup>1</sup> There is also the control character at `U+007F DELETE`, which is not trimmed by `trim()` method.

Answer (score 25):

The purpose of the two **standard** methods is to distinguish between this two cases:

`org.apache.common.lang.StringUtils.isBlank(" ")` (will return *true*).

`org.apache.common.lang.StringUtils.isEmpty(" ")` (will return *false*).

Your custom implementation of `isEmpty()` will return *true*.

---

**UPDATE:**

- `org.apache.common.lang.StringUtils.isEmpty()` is used to find if the String is length 0 or null.
- `org.apache.common.lang.StringUtils.isBlank()` takes it a step forward. It not only checks if the String is length 0 or null, but also checks if it is only a whitespace string.

In your case, you're trimming the String in *your* `isEmpty` method. The only difference that can occur now can't occur (the case you gives it `" "`) because you're [trimming](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) it (Removing the trailing whitespace - which is in this case is like removing *all* spaces).

Comment: More information: http://technohandle.blogspot.nl/2011/01/stringutilsisemtpty-vs.html

Comment: I think everybody is confused. Listen up. Maroun Maroun is right with the standard functions. But, the OP decided to write the function himself. Please note that normally, `isEmpty` would return `false`, but now the test is: `s.trim().length() > 0`.  Trimming `s` will remove all the whitespaces leading and trailing the string. Therefore, `" "` becomes `""`. This length == 0. Now it will return `false`!

Answer (score 14):

I would choose `isBlank()` over `isEmpty()` because `trim()` creates a new String object that has to be garbage collected later. `isBlank()` on the other hand does not create any objects.

Comment: That sounds like a good reason. However, think about the performance also. If the string was long, it would iterate over each character. Whereas, just by calling trim you could have made a short work of this.

Comment: @partha Thinking about performance, if the string was long it would take longer to copy it.

Comment: isBlank() immediately returns as soon as it encounters the first non-whitespace character. The only problem would be a long string with a single non-whitespace character at the end but then trim() would also have to iterate over the characters internally.

Comment: @partha trim must iterate too

Comment: @partha trim would not iterate over the whole string, just the first N+1  and last M+1 chars, where N and M are whitespace chars.

Comment: @Dariusz Neither would `isBlank` for that matter, which would actually do less iterating than `trim` would for non-empty strings with trailing white-space.

Comment: @devconsole No internal sharing happens in `String` as of OpenJDK 7 Update 6. You should reconsider your definition of "decent Java implementation".

Comment: @Marko Topolnik, yes you are right, sorry for the mistake. It is trim() -> substring() -> String(char[],int,int) which calls Arrays.copyOfRange() (and it also did so in Java 6).

Answer (score 4):

You could take a look at JSR 303 Bean Validtion wich contains the Annotatinos `@NotEmpty` and `@NotNull`. Bean Validation is cool because you can seperate validation issues from the original intend of the method.

Comment: I am familiar with JSR 303 and yes they are quite cool. My question was more about understanding what goes on behind the scenes. I guess when I actually need to make this validation, I could wrap either of these methods in discussion under the wraps of JSR 303, with custom annotations. But that was not the intent of the question. I was more interested in finding if there was a functional and / or peformance difference between the two implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you simply use a nested ternary operator to achieve this.Please look into the sample code 
`public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String s = null;
        String s1="";
        String s2="hello";
        System.out.println(" 1 "+check(s));
        System.out.println(" 2 "+check(s1));
        System.out.println(" 3 "+check(s2));
    }
    public static boolean check(String data)
    {
        return (data==null?false:(data.isEmpty()?false:true));
    }`

and the output is as follows

> 1 false 2 false 3 true

here the 1st 2 scenarios returns false (i.e null and empty)and the 3rd scenario returns true

Answer (score 0):

```
<% 
System.out.println(request.getParameter("userName")+"*");

if (request.getParameter("userName").trim().length() == 0 | request.getParameter("userName") == null) { %>
<jsp:forward page="HandleIt.jsp" />
<% }
 else { %>
Hello ${param.userName}
<%} %>
```

Answer (score 0):

This simple code will do enough:

```
public static boolean isNullOrEmpty(String str) {
    return str == null || str.trim().equals("");
}
```

And the unit tests:

```
@Test
public void testIsNullOrEmpty() {
    assertEquals(true, AcdsUtils.isNullOrEmpty(""));
    assertEquals(true, AcdsUtils.isNullOrEmpty((String) null));
    assertEquals(false, AcdsUtils.isNullOrEmpty("lol    "));
    assertEquals(false, AcdsUtils.isNullOrEmpty("HallO"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With Java 8, you could also use the Optional capability with filtering. To check if a string is blank, the code is pure Java SE without additional library.
The following code illustre a isBlank() implementation.

### String.trim() behaviour

```
!Optional.ofNullable(tocheck).filter(e -> e != null && e.trim().length() > 0).isPresent()
```

### StringUtils.isBlank() behaviour

```
Optional.ofNullable(toCheck)
    .filter(e -> 
        {
            int strLen;
            if (str == null || (strLen = str.length()) == 0) {
                return true;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < strLen; i++) {
                if ((Character.isWhitespace(str.charAt(i)) == false)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;

        })
    .isPresent()
```