# Java: find empty key in map:

Tags: java, collections, dictionary

I don't know why does not work with me. I have a empty keys in map but I cannot catch them.

```
Map<String, Long> map = new TreeMap<>();

//put data

map.entrySet().stream().forEach(e -> {
    if (e.getKey().equals("") || e.getKey().equals(" ") || e.getKey() == "" || e.getKey() == " ") {
        map.remove(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
    }
});
```

Edited:
I made a test for value:

```
     map.entrySet().stream() .forEach(e -> {
            if (e.getValue() == 133835) {
            System.out.println("key empty: " + e.getKey().isEmpty());
            System.out.println("key: >" + e.getKey() + "<");
            System.out.println("val: " + e.getValue());
        }
    });

    map = map.entrySet().stream().filter(
            p -> !"".equals(p.getKey().trim())).
            collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));


map.entrySet().stream() .forEach(e -> {
    if (e.getValue() == 133835) {

        System.out.println("key empty: " + e.getKey().isEmpty());
        System.out.println("key: >" + e.getKey() + "<");
        System.out.println("val: " + e.getValue());
    }
});
```

the result is:

```
key empty: false
key: >‏<
val: 133835
key empty: false
key: >‏<
val: 133835
```

I think this key is a gost )

Comment: "I have a empty keys in map but I can catch them." - this sentence makes no sense. What are you trying to do, and what's happening instead of what you were trying to make happen?

Comment: can you specify what the issue is? what does not work for you? what are you expecting to happen? how do you put the data?

Comment: From the edit, it seems he can'T catch/find the keys that are empty strings in his map.

Comment: Sorry for this mistake, I changed it to "cannot"

Comment: Obviously it's not empty. Figure out what's in it-where are the keys coming from.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16394787/checking-for-a-not-null-not-blank-string-in-java

Comment: No I don't think so, this subject is not duplicate. The character what I have is not empty and not blank and not null. I tested with StringUtil form your subject and I also tested with utf-8. There is 3 character what I think in this strange key.

Answer (score 1):

Try using e.getKey().trim().isEmpty()

Comment: I have now just System.out.println("found") this is not the problem

Comment: key.trim().isEmpty() sounds like the right way to check this. There may be exotic characters that are non-printing in your locale which trim() does not remove.

Comment: It still the same result: key empty: false

Answer (score 0):

first of all i would generally suggest to trim instead of checking for " " m(one space) and "" (empty string). And secondly that might be the case (a key with more than one space).

```
  "".equals(e.getKey().trim())
```

edit example:
           Map map = new TreeMap();

```
        map.put("",  1L);
        map.put(" ", 2L);
        map.put("3", 3L);

        map.entrySet().stream().forEach(e -> {
            System.out.println("key empty: " + e.getKey().isEmpty());
            System.out.println("key: >" + e.getKey() + "<");
            System.out.println("val: " + e.getValue());
        });
        map = map.entrySet().stream().filter(
                p -> !"".equals(p.getKey().trim())).
                collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));        

        map.entrySet().stream().forEach(e -> {
            System.out.println("key empty: " + e.getKey().isEmpty());
            System.out.println("key: >" + e.getKey() + "<");
            System.out.println("val: " + e.getValue());
        });
```

output is:

```
key empty: true
key: ><
val: 1
key empty: false
key: > <
val: 2
key empty: false
key: >3<
val: 3
AFTER REMOVAL
key empty: false
key: >3<
val: 3
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: deosn't answer it but might be a lead in the right direction. for me it appears an empty key for him is defined as an String matching one blank or "". So maybe a String with two bnalks qulifies as empty as well and will not be fdund by his code.

Comment: tried a filter?, something like:  `m.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(p ->  !"".equals(p.getKey().trim()))
    .collect(toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));`

Comment: How can I make this mothod toMap() ?

Comment: sry: Collectors.toMap (disclaimer: have not java8 compiler at hand).

Comment: maybe you could post what you put into your map? at least 2 entries and one of them with an "empty" key.

Comment: put >< arround your output. System.out.println("key: >" + e.getKey() + "<");

Comment: So, I puted your test see the result is not empty the key. It is no sense to check for empty

Comment: what code did you use? the `map = map.entrySet().stream().filter(
                p -> !"".equals(p.getKey().trim())).
                collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));` if so, i give up.

Comment: See now your test, it stil not empty. I think it is better if there is a possibility to check utf-8 characters

Comment: Answers are there to answer the question. For hints, tips and questions to the OP, please use comments. Also, a hint from myself, don't compare a string to `""`, but use `isEmpty` instead (unless you expect it to be nullable).

Comment: mr. smartypants, you should know i can only comment on my posts, as i have a reputation lower than 50. with you downvoting me, it won't get any better.